# Uncaught Error: Couldn't load file:///android_asset/www/less/app.less (200) at file:///android_asset/www/js/lib/less.js:15

Tags: android, cordova, less

I am getting following  error while trying to run this phonegap 1.4/adnroid 8 app on my dev machine:

Uncaught Error: Couldn't load file:///android_asset/www/less/app.less (200) at file:///android_asset/www/js/lib/less.js:15

And this android/phonegap app is "running on emulator/phone" but shows up with NO styling(because it is not able to load less.js i guess).

Both the files are part of the app directory structure and so I am not loading anything from internet(because I can see these 2 files under www).

Most of the solutions on internet talk about internet connectivity but these files are present locally but for some reason app is not able to load! Also to make sure these files not loading anything from internet I added proxy, and "uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"  is present in AndroidManifest.xml.

Are there any other settings I should check? Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution: Compile your .less files into css files and include it directly in HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Modify less js source file, add this line:

```
href = href.replace( "file:///android_asset/www/", "");
```

inside loadStyleSheet function, before calling xhr function (somewhere around #4150 ).

That should work. Tested on Less 1.3.3

Less is using absolute path when doing ajax call to get Less files defined in 'link' tags.
We just made that absolute link - relative.

Answer (score 0):

Do not convert your stylesheet extension , keep it as same (eg:styles.css) but not styles.less

and follow the same

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
```

I got same problem while using less-1.3.3 version!